# How to maintain wordpress site blogs in production and staging?

Tags: admin, blog, woocommerce-offtopic, subdomains, maintenance

I work as a website admin in my company. We are selling digital products using WooCommerce. We wanted to have staging and production in order to avoid any site down.

So in staging we use to create blogs from our blog team and then we'll push it to production. The problem is when any post is created in staging say it has a ID 586 then in the mean if an order is made in production then its ID also 586. Since WooCommerce order is also a Post, I cannot push site either from production to staging or staging to production to have both Because the POST ID will should be unique.

Is staging and production maintenance are only for **Development Purpose**?

If it is only for Development Purpose then how can i manage my blogs? Because my blog team members some time breaks the sites. How should I limit them and have a good running site.

Should i have separate site for Shop but this may affect SEO.

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Which role the bloggers have? When you say they break the site, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have does indeed sound more like production and development. General practice it that between these two the data only goes from production to development, but never the other way.

Having true staging, you can push the data from to production, is challenging precisely for the reasons you describe. There are solutions around, but even those on commercial and pricey side don't quite promise reliable two-way synchronization with live environment.

The low hanging fruit for you would be to find and eliminate those ways in which your content authors can break the site. Their roles and permissions should be locked down and there should be procedure for content going live, rather than authors just pushing publish.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer +1. Shouldn't i have separate site in sub-domain for woocommerce purpose alone. For example www.shop.example.com so the shop will be safe and blogs will be separate.

Comment: @rram that might be a sound idea, I am not dealing with ecommerce site personally enough to recommend on their specifics. :)

Comment: Thank you. If authors edit/create any post in live at the same time an order is created, wouldn't there any clash in post entry even though database data entry happen in Milli seconds?