# Staging sites, how do you manage synchronising updates in the DB?

Tags: database, staging, sync

It is broadly accepted that developers should test updates through a staging site before releasing them to the live server, however once the development updates require modifications in Wordpress DB, things get complicated, as users in the live site will update the DB too.

The only (muddled) flow I can imagine is the following:

1. Test on a local server (WAMP, XAMP, etc)
2. Once ready to deploy, put the live site in maintenance mode
3. Backup live site (Duplicator, sqldump, etc)
4. Create a clone of locked live site to the staging site
5. Upload modifications from local environment to the staging site
6. Test the staging site
7. Push the staging site to live.
8. Remove maintenance mode

Drawbacks of the flow above:

- downtimes may be longer than expected for users while the developer
  is carefully testing updates in the staging site;
- may require manual management of modifications: for instance, siteorigin pagebuilder layouts are stored in the db, so once a layout is modified, it must be imported manually in the staging site; in this case it could be adequate to simply drop & import pages into the staging site, and if working, importing them in the live site

I wonder if is there a better and more automated way to achieve this.

What do you think?

EDIT, as requested, some solutions have been proposed in the past but none offers a definitive solution:

- 9/2010 - [Database synchronization between dev/staging and production](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/database-synchronization-between-dev-staging-and-production)
- 12/2011 - [Deploying Updated or New Plugins That Modify the wp_options Table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35280/deploying-updated-or-new-plugins-that-modify-the-wp-options-table)
- 9/2014 - [How to upload local changes to a live server without overriding new posts/pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160642/how-to-upload-local-changes-to-a-live-server-without-overriding-new-posts-pages)
- 1/2015 - [How to maintain wordpress site blogs in production and staging?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174529/how-to-maintain-wordpress-site-blogs-in-production-and-staging)

Comment: @Dan9, I thought it would ba safer to minimize access to the live site. Is it a common habit to edit layouts on the live site? Maybe I am worrying too much!

Comment: Well, you can create, update, delete, restore them. What're you worrying about?

Comment: So it is usual to upload layouts without testing in the staging site? What is your typical workflow (local/staging/live)?

Comment: Take a look at [wp-sync-db plugin](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db).

Comment: Is it reliable? Are you using this tool?

Comment: No :). We often backup live db, dump local db and import it to staging site. If it's ok, import it to live site too. Most of steps are automated with shell scripts and wp-cli.

Comment: We have clients who follow strict git driven flow. With that, we create db migration scripts for taking care of the db. Each time a migration script is run,  current db structure is backed up and pushed to cloud. Ofcourse, proper testing and staging environment is needed before pushing anything to live.

Comment: How does the staging-to-live flow occurs? Once the staging test has succeeded do you push everything back to live or only what has changed? In the second case, do you synchronize live db with the staging one or you never push db data to live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer hosting providers that cater specifically to WordPress usually have tools in place to ease this pain. I put my clients on Pantheon which has this [neat Git-enabled workflow](https://pantheon.io/docs/pantheon-workflow/), where code only moves up (from dev to staging to production) and DB stuff only moves down (vice versa from the code). Copying a database from production to staging is one click with their interface. Provided this workflow is respected, this pretty much eliminates the issue of ever messing up the production database, enabling me to always test my changes on a fresh clone of production DB data in either staging on development.

One doesn't have to use Pantheon - you can adopt a similar approach in your process using your own tools (Git + a DB cloning plugin like WP Migrate DB). I just find this way works well for me.

Question: why would you put your production site in maintenance mode while testing staging? There shouldn't be a need for that in a majority of cases. The only case I can think of is having some sort of very brittle system highly sensitive to additional user data being fed into it, with a catastrophic bug to boot - but that would likely be indicative of a different, larger, problem where one would need to rethink their product's entire architecture.

Comment: My provider allows creating one-click staging sites and push-to-live with a granular selection on tables being rewritten, nevertheless I still need locking users while the final test is run because part of the deployment is injecting developer-side data in the DB (sitebuilder page layouts for example are stored in the DB), requiring users to stop updating during this phase. If you have a better idea how to achieve this step I would be glad to share with you!

Comment: BTW, do you go through the dev/staging/live flow each time a little modification has been made? For example, slightly changing the layout of a page within the editor, or modifying a menu

Comment: Yep - files go through dev -> staging -> prod every time (perhaps you can disable staging or dev - don't remember). Dev is for the dev team, staging is for QA or designer/client approval before pushing to prod.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VersionPress](https://versionpress.net/) which brings GIT versioning to the whole process (files and database)

As described on their site:

> **VersionPress provides painless staging**. This means that you can easily
>   create a safe testing environment for your changes and only merge them
>   back when they are ready. Merge is the key word here – VersionPress
>   handles situations where your live site had new content in the
>   meantime seamlessly.

Comment: How can I verify reliability of this tool?